# Regular Expression to find table name used in join condition and column used in join condition

Tags: sql, regex, decoding, regexp-replace, snowflake-schema

How to find table name and column used in join condition using regular expressions?

select * from table1
left outer join table2
on table1.column1 = table2.column1

result = table_name
column1

I need regular expressions which is woring is snowflake.

Comment: Don't use comments for additional information, edit your question instead.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different regular expression implementations.)

Comment: please, please edit your question and format it properly and include the relevant comments it the question itself. And remove them afterwards.

Comment: What if the table is aliased? (it should be). What if you are using sub queries?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this regular expression using PHP's PCRE engine (to use back references and the extended notation with comments):

https://regex101.com/r/x99nHu/2

The regex:

```
\bJOIN\s+                      # JOIN keyword + spaces.
`?(?<table>\w+)`?\s+           # Capture table name in group n°1 + spaces
(?:AS\s+`?(?<alias>\w+)`?\s+)? # Optional alias (captured in group n°2).
ON\s+                          # ON keyword + spaces.
.*?                            # Ungreedy match everything because we don't
                               # know in wich order the ON condition is written.
`?(?:\k<table>|\k<alias>)`?\.  # Table name or alias + dot.
`?(\w+)\`?                     # Table field.
```

I'm using the following flags:

- **g** for **g**lobal matches (perhaps not for your case. This depends
  if you have several JOIN statements or not).
- **i** for case **i**nsensitive.
- **s** so that the dot matches new lines also (as the ON condition can
  be written on several lines).
- **x** for e**x**tended syntax (allowing comments and ignoring spaces).

I took in consideration the fact that a SQL query could be written with
backticks around the table, alias or field names.

I also took in consideration an optional table alias (which is common).

The `\k<table>` and `\k<alias>` are some back references to the
capturing groups created above.

Explained:

- `\bJOIN\s+` matches the beginning of a word, then the word "JOIN"
  followed by one or several spaces, tabs or new lines.
- `` `? `` matches an optional backtick.
- `(?<table>\w+)` will capture a word into a group named "table".
- `.*?` in the middle is to match anything in an ungreedy way. As we
  don't know how the ON condition will be written, we have to jump over
  possible conditions until we match the table name or alias with its
  field name.
- `(?:\k<table>|\k<alias>)` is a non-capturing group to match either
  the table name or it's alias.

You can test it here also with **JavaScript** instead of the PCRE engine, but you'll notice that it doesn't react exactly the same and
doesn't deliver the correct field name at query one, where no alias
is given and where the condition exposes the field from the main
table first. I especially changed the field names so that you can see
it too:

```js
// The regular expression written in JavaScript syntax (extended doesn't exist).
const regex = /\bJOIN\s+`?(?<table>\w+)`?\s+(?:AS\s+`?(?<alias>\w+)`?\s+)?ON\s+.*?`?(?:\k<table>|\k<alias>)`?\.`?(\w+)\`?/gis;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let findButton = document.getElementById('find');
  let resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
  
  findButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let sql = document.getElementById("sql").value;
    let match;
    let results = [];
    
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the output.
    
    while ((match = regex.exec(sql)) !== null) {
      let result = `Table: <code>${match[1]}</code>`;
      if (match[2] !== undefined) {
        result += ` (aliased by <code>${match[2]}</code>)`;
      }
      result += `, field: <code>${match[3]}</code>`;
      results.push(result);
    }
    
    if (results.length) {
      let ul = document.createElement('ul');
      resultsDiv.appendChild(ul);
      results.forEach((result, i) => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = result;
        ul.appendChild(li);
      });
    } else {
      let p = document.createElement('p');
      p.classList.add('error');
      p.innerHTML = 'No results found!';
      resultsDiv.appendChild(p);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  font: 16px/1.4 Arial, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 40em;
}

code {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 0 .3em;
  border-radius: .2em;
}

.error {
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <label for="sql">SQL query:</label><br>
    <textarea name="sql" id="sql" cols="64" rows="30">select *
from table1
left outer join table_name
  on table1.column_main_table = table_name.column_join_table;

SELECT
  u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`, m.`title`
FROM
  `users` AS u
INNER JOIN
  `movies` AS m
  ON m.`id` = u.`movie_id`;

SELECT
  m.`type`, u.`genre`
FROM
  `movies` AS m
LEFT JOIN
  `users` AS u
  ON u.`movie_id` = m.`id`
GROUP BY
  m.`type`;

SELECT  u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`, `movies`.`title`
FROM `users` AS u
RIGHT JOIN `movies`
ON `movies`.`id` = u.`movie_id`
WHERE `movies`.`id` > 100;</textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="find">Find the join table and field</button>
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</form>
```

The PCRE, Java and .NET engine are behaving the same, as we want. So
for JavaScript, we may have to change the regex but I don't know how.